# Sticky section header disappear when collapse section in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView that setting with custom section header. When I tap section header, it will collapse/expand. Section header stick at the top when scroll down

My problem is when I scroll a section to 50% and tap section header to collapse, current section header will disappear, It are replaced by next section header, user have to scroll up to see the previous section. It's kind of bad UX
Any idea to fix this.
Thank you so much

Demo: https://freeimage.host/i/HfyjRDv
My code: https://codefile.io/f/P3yiUQKkCB2L0VW13n9N

```
    var hiddenSections = Set<Int>()
    let tableViewData = [
        ["1","2","3","4","5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
        ["1","2","3","4","5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
        ["1","2","3","4","5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
        ["1","2","3","4","5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
        ["1","2","3","4","5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
    ]
```

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.tableViewData.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if self.hiddenSections.contains(section) {
            return 0
        }
        
        return self.tableViewData[section].count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.tableViewData[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let sectionButton = UIButton()
        sectionButton.setTitle(String(section),
                               for: .normal)
        sectionButton.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        sectionButton.tag = section
        sectionButton.addTarget(self,
                                action: #selector(self.hideSection(sender:)),
                                for: .touchUpInside)

        return sectionButton
    }
    
    @objc
    private func hideSection(sender: UIButton) {
        let section = sender.tag
        
        func indexPathsForSection() -> [IndexPath] {
            var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
            
            for row in 0..<self.tableViewData[section].count {
                indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: row,
                                            section: section))
            }
            
            return indexPaths
        }
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        
        if self.hiddenSections.contains(section) {
            self.hiddenSections.remove(section)
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPathsForSection(),
                                      with: .fade)
        } else {
            self.hiddenSections.insert(section)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPathsForSection(),
                                      with: .fade)
        }
    
        self.tableView.endUpdates()

    }
```

Currently, I have try by using "tableView.scrollTo" but not good idea

Expected:

Current section header don't disappear when collapse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlpIc.gif)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDjyP.gif

Comment: UITableView(style: .plain)

Comment: Thanks @ZeeshanAhmadII. I'm using .plain to have Stick Header Section behavior. As I explained, section header always disappear if user scroll to 50% of a section and tap section header to collapse, tableview will auto scroll to next section header

Comment: this is because you are inserting and removing sections not rows

Answer (score 0):

Do it professionally

```
public struct Xection {
    let rows: [XRow]
    var collapsed: Bool
    
    public init(rows: [XRow], collapsed: Bool = false) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.collapsed = collapsed
    }
    
    static func all() -> [Xection] {
        let s = [Xection(rows: [XRow(name: "1", icon: ""),
                                XRow(name: "2", icon: ""),
                                XRow(name: "3", icon: "")]),
                 Xection(rows: [XRow(name: "5", icon: ""),
                                         XRow(name: "11", icon: ""),
                                         XRow(name: "zz", icon: "")]),
                 Xection(rows: [XRow(name: "zz", icon: ""),
                                         XRow(name: "z", icon: ""),
                                         XRow(name: "z", icon: "")])]
       
        
        return s
    }
}
public struct XRow {
    
    var name: String
    var icon:String
    
    public init(name: String,icon:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.icon = icon
    }
}
```

then in your class

```
var sections = Xection.all()


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].collapsed ? 0 : sections[section].rows.count
    }
    
    // Cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.sections[indexPath.section].rows[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }
   
    // Header
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            let sectionButton = UIButton()
            sectionButton.setTitle(String(section),
                                   for: .normal)
            sectionButton.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
            sectionButton.tag = section
            sectionButton.addTarget(self,
                                    action: #selector(self.hideSection(sender:)),
                                    for: .touchUpInside)

            return sectionButton
        }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 85.0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 85.0
    }

    @objc
    private func hideSection(sender: UIButton) {
        sections[sender.tag].collapsed = !sections[sender.tag].collapsed
        tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: sender.tag) as IndexSet, with: .automatic)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry, this is just a simple test project. I still cannot resolve this problem. When collapse first section header, uitableview still scroll to next section. I think this is the behavior of tableview, maybe.